# Laravel specification search

Tags: sql, json, laravel, search, e-commerce

Im building ecommerce website and i want to ask what is the best way to search specifications of product.I have a field in database with specification that can be stored as json or as php array.Is there any tutorial that i can use to output unique specification for example category CPU, and to put different CPU brands under that category so user can decide which specification to add to search filter.To give you a perspective i want to make something like this

[Amazon.com search field image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g6YgT.png)

Comment: Do you have active model for all the tables? what you will be using for this eloquent or DB query for this? Why you are not storing the specifications of what you will be filtering in individual columns? why in JSON?

Comment: @sibabratswain I'm new to Laravel so sorry if I'm wrong.I have Product model for products table.I will be using Eloquent and im not storing specficiation in individual columns because the specification(like model, memory,etc.) change from product to product, then ill need to create like 40+ fields for that.I think about json because i really dont know but i think using json because i dont need to serialize and unserialize it like php array and i think its faster because i can access it very easily.But i hope someone will tell me better solution.

Comment: Using SQL for sophisticated search like this would be very very very slow, I recommend using a service like [Algolia](https://algolia.com)

Comment: @Amar you are not using NoSQL DB, so in SQL for filtration, it is more suitable if you have separate columns. You can achieve what you want but in the query, it will be difficult to handle as the data in JSON. To make it simple you need to fetch it and do array filter operation in controller.

Comment: @Saly3301 Do you have tutorial for algolia search like this one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could search though `whereJsonContains()` method.

for example;

let assume there are some filter in your form as below

```
brands
 - intel
 - amd

Number of core
 - 2
 - 4
 - 8
```

Now let build a query to get filtered results

```
Cpu::whereJsonContains("preferences->brand",$request->brand)
    ->whereJsonContains("preferences->noc", $request->noc)
    ->get();
```

But I'm not sure if storing such a json data in your database is a good practice. Because it's not store and display case, there will generic results depends those specifications.

Comment: Your answer is what i need but what i learn that algolia is best way to solve this.